# Mysql: What is the expected write performance on a fresh innodb table durng free server condition

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I would like to know the expected write performance for the below server configurations.

```
OS: ubuntu 10.04 
Processor: 2 cores each with 2.6 GHz on same die
RAM : 2GB RAM
hard disc: 450GB
Mysql version 5.1.61 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8MB
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8MB
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1
log-bin : YES
rpm: 7200
```

I am doing the inserts from the same server with mysql like dump import.
my dump will has individual inserts one after another, no  transactions.
table is pretty simple with 5 attributes no indexes apart from the primary key in ID and an empty one.

Current performance is 6 minutes to insert 10K records.

```
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
UDAY
```

Comment: my.cnf is with default configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following articles of interest. Pay particular attention to:

- innodb_buffer_pool_size
- innodb_log_file_size
- innodb_log_buffer_size
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
- start transaction and commit/rollback
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/
- http://vimeo.com/20990641
- http://jpipes.com/presentations/perf_tuning_best_practices.pdf
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

A simple example:

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop procedure if exists load_test_data;

delimiter #
create procedure load_test_data()
begin

declare v_max int unsigned default 10000;
declare v_counter int unsigned default 0;

  truncate table users;
  start transaction;
  while v_counter < v_max do
        insert into users (username) values (concat('username ', v_counter+1));
    set v_counter=v_counter+1;
  end while;
  commit;
end #

delimiter ;


mysql> call load_test_data();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.69 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from users;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    10000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Are these the stats with innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 1. for my server when i set this to 2 only i am able to get the above performance. Anyways i will look in the links provided. thank you foo.. Please confirm me the innodb flush setting of your set up.